# Country list selection box - Set one as selected

Tags: php, html

I have a country list of every country in a form to get a parcel quote.

When a user presses the "Get Quote" button, all the text forms retain the information previously entered using PHP.

How can I do this with the country list box? As I can't have PHP on every option checking if that is the country selected and adding "Selected" to the html.

Is there a better way other than generating the country list from a file in a loop?

**EDIT:**

Going for the method of looping through a file, and checking..
This is what I have so far:

```
$countries = fopen("includes/countries.txt", "r");
$countries = explode(";", $countries);
```

Then in the HTML:

```
<select id="countries" name="countries">
<?php
    foreach ($countries as $country){
        echo("<option value=\"" . $country . "\">" . $country . "</option>");
    }

?>
</select>
```

Not yet finished.

Comment: you can make array of coutries and then using foreach, add them in select box

Comment: Loop through the countries and echo selected for the country that matches. This is the best way to do it.

Comment: Thanks. I have decided to do this. Country list in a text file, then loading the file, looping through. Thanks again.

Comment: What does your code look like now?

Comment: @putvande Added my code above

Comment: Using textfiles as data storage is unperformant and unsecure. Please don't do that. Use a common Database to handle data-storage. Beside the fact that there are lots of complete mysql-tables i.e. containing all countries, or web-APIs delivering the data to your App.

Comment: @xcy7e IT will be a database later. This is only to show a client how it would work.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have an array with your countries stored. You could try something like this:

```
$countries = array('Albania', 'Egypt');
$selected_country_id = $_GET['c_id']; // You may need to change this to match with your code
$country_selected = array();

foreach($countries as $country) {
    if($country['id'] == $selected_country_id) {
        $country_selected[ $country['id'] ] = ' selected ';
    } else {
        $country_selected[ $country['id'] ] = '';
    }
}
```

Then, assuming that you dynamically add your Select-Options, do this:

```
// In your each-fn

echo '<option value="' . $country['id'] . '" ' . $country_selected[ $country['id'] ] . '>' . $country['name'] . '</option>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would be better

```
foreach ($countries as $country) {
    ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $country" <?php echo ($country == $_POST['country'] ? 'selected' : ''; ?>><?php echo $country; ?></option>
    <?php

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<select id="countries" name="countries">
    <?php
        foreach ($countries as $country){
            if(isset($_POST["country"]) && $_POST["country"] == $country){
              $sel = "selected";
            }else { $sel= ""; }
            echo("<option value=\"" . $country . "\"" .$sel.">" . $country . "</option>");
        }

    ?>
    </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Get All Country-State-City Selectbox ....!!!

See Link : [GitHub](https://github.com/ganeshlore/Country-State-City-Select-Box)